# How modify the generated manifest for requested execution level

Tags: vsto, clickonce, outlook-addin

I make an Outlook add-in with the VSTO. But When i build, the value in the generated manifest are not the desired ones.

The generation done :

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

And i want :

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

How can i changed the this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Execution manifests are only applicable to the exe files; COM addins are dlls loaded in the outlook.exe process space. Your code will run with whatever privileges the parent process (Outlook) is running.

Comment: So how can i display my region for a standard user?

Comment: Yes a bug has been report to me. A standard user can not display the UI region. But some add-in's feature work.

Comment: You need to debug it and figure out what's causing it. Trying to force Outlook to run with admin privileges is not really a solution.